# Windows 8 metro apps Display name of app

Tags: c#, windows-8

can u tell me how to hide or remove display name of my app?? i want to add an image logo not Displayname of app.
thanx

Answer (score 1):

Change your `Package.appxmanifest` file's section `DefaultTile`:

```
<DefaultTile ShowName="noLogos" />
```

Or by using integrated Visual Studio designer.